# Deciding on Javascript pub/sub pattern for application

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, publish-subscribe

I'm looking to use `pub/sub` to filter a list of cards that are displayed as a result of a search.

Each card will have data on a specific athlete such as, speed, agility, age etc. I will then have a filter drop-down `<select>` that allows the user to sort the cards by those attributes.

I'm using `Node.js` to render the page, which calls `JSON` data from an API and is rendered server side using `handlebars`.

I do not wish to use frameworks, just pure JS. Would `pub/sub` be good for this? If so, how would you deal with sorting the cards?

Comment: *Would pub/sub be good for this?* - it possibly would, or it possibly wouldn't. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case. Since this is server side, it's unclear what you intend to publish and subscribe. *I will then have a filter drop-down <select> that allows the user to sort the cards by those attributes* - this would make sense for client-side app, but for server side this will likely be done in separate request.

Comment: It's a high level overview at the moment so no code as such. I guess the question is, if it's done client side (no more requests to server after first render) would a pub/sub pattern be the best solution.

Comment: It possibly would, or it possibly wouldn't. This totally depends on what client-side app looks like. Observables and RxJS in particular are quite close with pub/sub pattern and they can be efficiently used in frameworks and libs that support them (Angular, Cycle, etc) for the thing you're describing.